# How to split a number into several numbers

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have this number 100011000410005, and I wanted to get 3 different numbers like: 10001 10004 10005 out of the big number. any advice for this task? Thanks

Comment: What is your splitting criteria? Length? The phase of the moon?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -r 's/.{5}/& /g' file
10001 10004 10005
```

If that doesn't do what you want, edit your question to clarify your requirements.